# How to pass to a new line after detecting a number in a string in php?

Tags: php

I want to pass to a new line after detecting the number in the string. So I want output to be:

```
nameone
2 nametwo
3 namethree
```

here is the code that I am running in php:

```
$str="nameone 2 nametwo 3 namethree";
for ($i=0;$i<=strlen($str)-1;$i++){
    $char=$str[$i];
    if (is_int($char)){
        echo "\n".$char;
    }
    else if (!is_int($char)){
        echo $char;
    }
}
```

however the output is `nameone 2 name two 3 namethree`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`is_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) checks with the datatype too and not just the numbers inside it in string form.

For your case, use [`is_numeric`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) like below:

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "nameone 2 nametwo 3 namethree";

for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($str) - 1; $i++){
    $char = $str[$i];
    if (is_numeric($char)){
        echo "\n".$char;
    }else{
        echo $char;
    }
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/cb23c)

---

**Alternative Way:**

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to achieve the same result. Just match all digits using `\d` and use a line break appended with the backtracked group of the regex like below:

```
<?php

$str = preg_replace('/(\d)/', PHP_EOL . '\0' , $str);

echo $str;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/1dbf3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function PHP_EOL to add a line break after detecting a number in a string.

Comment: `\n` would also work just fine.